# get code line with __LINE__

Tags: c++, c, macros

I tried to print the line number of the current code by using:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void err (char *msg)
{
    printf ("%s : %d" , msg , __LINE__);
}

int main ( int argc , char **argv )
{
    ERR ("fail..");
    return 0;
}
```

But i always get the wrong line number , it should be `10` instead of `5` , how can i fix this ?

Also i tried to use some macro:

`#define ERR (msg) do { printf ("%s : %d\n" , msg , __LINE__); } while (0)`

and result in error: `msg not declared`

Comment: `__LINE__` is on line 5, so `5` is the correct answer, no?

Comment: @hochl , no , it should be where it's called , in this case , 10

Comment: Yeah, figured it and posted an example below ^^

Comment: Nobody yet has mentioned why your original ERR macro didn't work -- it's because of the space between "ERR" and "(msg)".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#define ERR(msg) printf("%s : %d", (msg), __LINE__)
```

Should do the trick.

You do not need the function!

Comment: This is the problem with macros; once you add even a small taste of them to you program, they start to infect everything.

Comment: Maybe but this particular task cannot be accomplished without macros.

Comment: don't put a semicolon inside a macro, otherwise you will get problems when you place it in some `if/else` condition.

Comment: Oops - a typo. BTW - Should always put stuff after `if` in braces. Saves a lot of grief when people add an extra line of code an expect it to work.

Comment: @JohnDibling - Right, but only because `__LINE__` is a macro. Once you try to generalize its use, you have to use more macros. If you want to generalize the use of those macro "routines", you'll need **more** macros. So use of the `__LINE__` macro slowly infects your whole program with macros.

Comment: @T.E.D.:  I'm not sure I get your point.  Using a device such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196431/passing-the-caller-file-line-to-a-function-without-using-macro/4196475#4196475) to implement logging with filename & line numbers doesn't "infect" your code with macros.  It simply uses the best tool for the job where it's needed.  Isn't that a good thing?

Answer (score 10):

`__LINE__` will give you the line on which it appears, which is ***always*** line 5.

To make this work, you will need to pass in `__LINE__` as a separate parameter.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void err (char *msg, int line)
{
    printf ("%s : %d" , msg , line);
}

int main ( int argc , char **argv )
{
    err("fail..", __LINE__);
    return 0;
}
```

An even better way to do this would be to define the invocation of such method as a *macro*, like so:

```
#define PRINTERR(msg) err((msg), __LINE__)
```

Answer (score 6):

`__LINE__` gets the *current* line, meaning the line that it was called on. You need to pass it as a parameter:

```
ERR ("fail..", __LINE__);
```

Otherwise it will always be the line inside your error function, **5** in your example. Change your function to accept an `int` type for the `__LINE__` macro.

I would use the macro that @Ed Heal answered with. Also, the reason you are getting "msg not declared" is <strike>that variables in macros need to be enclosed in parentheses (i.e. `(msg)`).</strike> because there is a space between the macro's name and the parenthesis that starts the parameter list.

Comment: i think it's actually i put a space between `ERR` and '(msg)' , because this one works: `#define ERR(msg) printf ("%s : %d\n" , msg , __LINE__)`

Comment: No, you don't have to enclose parameters in parentheses. Macro replacement is just textual replacement.

Comment: It's a good idea to put enclose msg within parentheses because msg could be an expression. Not sure if it's necessary in this case but it's a good rule of thumb.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `ERR` a macro:

```
#define ERR(msg) fprintf(stderr, "ERROR on line %d: %s\n", __LINE__, (msg))
```

Comment: `fprintf` needs a `FILE*` as first parameter