# Custom error function C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a way to get the line the code is being executed on?

For example:

```
int death() {
  cout << "An error has occurred on line " << line << endl;
  exit(128);
}
```

Then if I call death() function on line 64 it tells me that the error occurred on line 64.

**EDIT:**
Most people seem to be telling me to use the `__LINE__` macro. I know you can do that:

```
#define DEATH(message) death(__LINE__, message)
```

where

```
int death(int line, string message) {
  cout << "An error has occurred at line << line << endl;
}
```

But I'm thinking of using it in such a way:

```
string readFile(string file) {
  string str;
  ifstream stream(file);
  if (!stream) { death(); } //if this is line 23, it prints line 23
  stream >> str;
  stream.close();
  return str;
}

//instead of printing line 64 if readFile() is executed on line 64
```

And using the `__LINE__` macro alone only returns the line at which the `death()` function was executed. In other words, if I execute `readFile()` at line 64, I want `death()` to print line 64, not the line at which it was defined inside the `readFile()` function.

Comment: So, are you expecting `death()` to *terminate* the program as well as log the error? If so, I think that you simply need to have a function call such as `death(__LINE__)` and call `exit()` within the `death()` function. If you simply want `death()` to end the *current function*, then just add a `return` statement directly after you call `death()`.

Comment: Looks like you want stack trace?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is the terminology

Comment: There is no portable way to get a stack trace. It is very much platform/compiler dependent. On Windows you have `CaptureStackBackTrace` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204633.aspx) for example. With gcc on other platforms you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-gcc-c-app-crashes

Comment: If you only want a *single* line number (rather than a complete stack trace) then you can simply store the output of `__LINE__` at an earlier point. I've updated my answer to give an example of this; it doesn't report the *calling* line, but I think that the basic idea could work - perhaps with a bit of pre-processor trickery to insert the `CAN_DIE` macro before each call to `someFunction()`?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [`__LINE__`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html) macro:

> The standard predefined macros are specified by the relevant language standards, so they are available with all compilers that implement those standards. Older compilers may not provide all of them. Their names all start with double underscores.
>
> `__FILE__`
>
> This macro expands to the name of the current input file, in the form of a C string constant. This is the path by which the
>   preprocessor opened the file, not the short name specified in
>   `#include` or as the input file name argument. For example,
>   `/usr/local/include/myheader.h` is a possible expansion of this macro.
>
> `__LINE__`
>
> This macro expands to the current input line number, in the form of a decimal integer constant. While we call it a predefined macro,
>   it's a pretty strange macro, since its "definition" changes with each
>   new line of source code.
>
> `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are useful in generating an error message to report an inconsistency detected by the program; the message can state the source line at which the inconsistency was detected.

If you want to get a line number other than the *current* line, you'll need to store the line number from `__LINE__` at an earlier point. For example, this code gets the *first* line number of the function that calls `death()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Set up some stuff to keep track of where you died. */
int DEATH_LINE = 0;
#define CAN_DIE DEATH_LINE = __LINE__;
void death() { printf("OH NO, YOU DIED AT LINE %d!\n", DEATH_LINE); }

/* This function can die, so get the first line number using CAN_DIE */
int someFunction() { CAN_DIE
  printf("Hello, World!\n");
  death();
  printf("Goodbye, Cruel World!\n");
  return 0;
}

int main() { return someFunction(); }
```

This produces the following output:

```
Hello, World!
OH NO, YOU DIED AT LINE 10!
Goodbye, Cruel World!

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.009 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Alternatively, you could get the line number that *calls* the function as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int DEATH_LINE = 0;
#define CAN_DIE(x) ((DEATH_LINE = __LINE__), (x));
void death() { printf("OH NO, YOU DIED AT LINE %d!\n", DEATH_LINE); }

int someFunction() {
  printf("Hello, World!\n");
  death();
  printf("Goodbye, Cruel World!\n");
  return 123;
}

int main() { return CAN_DIE(someFunction()); }
```

This produces the following output:

```
Hello, World!
OH NO, YOU DIED AT LINE 15!
Goodbye, Cruel World!

Process returned 123 (0x7B)   execution time : 0.008 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Note that the second example requires the calling function to wrap the other function (i.e. the one that actually calls `death()`) in a macro to set the current line number correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`__LINE__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html).

The `__LINE__` macro is often combined with the `__FILE__` macro, which expands to the current file name.

```
#define ERR(msg) printf("%s : %d", (msg), __LINE__)

const char * msg ="An error has occurred on line ";
cout << ERR(msg) << endl;
```

[Get code line with **LINE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929291/get-code-line-with-line)

Comment: Yeah here it is again [Get code line with LINE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929291/get-code-line-with-line)

Answer (score 1):

You need to mix macro and functions:

```
int death_at(int line) {
   cerr << "An error has occurred on line " << line << endl;
}
#define DEATH() death_at(__LINE__)
```

You might even have

```
#define FAILURE(Out) do { cerr << __FILE__ << ":" __LINE__ \
                          << ": " << Out << endl; } while(0)
```

then you could code:

```
FAILURE("x is " << x)
```

And you might even use some `throw` near the end of your `FAILURE` macro definition.

Answer (score 0):

Use `__LINE__`

```
void foo() {
  if (somethingWrong) { death(__LINE__); } // Pass this line number to death()
}

void death(int line) {
  cout << "An error has occurred on line " << line << endl;
}
```