# finding who creates object via smart pointer

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, smart-pointers

I posted few days back regarding memory leaks with smart pointers. Now I am able to find out which objects are leaking memory but I am not able to figure it out from where they are leaking memory.

I am using the same code as mentioned here
[Detecting memory leak in reference counted objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826887/detecting-memory-leak-in-reference-counted-objects)

I have read lot of comments but none of them explains properly. I tried using macros **FILE** and **LINE** , both of them prints file and line of refmanager class .

Is there a good way to debug this issue.Please point to some nice example also.

Comment: You're saying that the logs indicate the file & line # of the smart pointer class itself?  Or the location that called `new`?

Comment: log indicates line of smart pointer class itself..any idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to use Valgrind (on Linux and Mac) and some similar tool on Windows.

You could also in the constructor of the smart-pointer take a backtrace (using the function backtrace() function on Linux and Mac) or a similar function from dbghelp.dll on windows and then save the backtrace somewhere on allocation and remove the backtrace on deallocation. Then on exit print all the remaining backtraces.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can use the new memory diagnostics tools in Visual Studio 2015:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/10/21/memory-profiling-in-visual-c-2015.aspx